# from 3 dummies to one dependent variable for regression model

Tags: regression

I have three dummies related to three political aspects of "TRUST"..

1)"Government ministers trust" measures trust on government ministers;
2) "Prime Minister trust" measures trust on prime minister;
3) "Program Implementation Trust" measures trust on the ability to implement the Governmente program.

For each of these questions the answer is the same (no trust=1 ; trust=2)

I need to have unique dependent variable y "TRUST" based on the three dummies, and then build a regression model.. Supposing the three dummies estimate equally I proposed this solution based on all the possible backhoe values of dummies:

[image]

Point is I don't know if this solution is "statistically" correct (maybe I'm ingnoring collinearity?)..

What do you suggest me? I mean both the way to build the dependent variable, both the regression model to use later..

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: So you have three binary variables and want to combine them into a single variable measuring the common concept?

Comment: Do you want to weight each of the 3 "TRUST" estimates equally, or are some types of "TRUST" more important than others?

Comment: Thnak you for the answers,, Yes the three dummy estimates equally!!

Comment: Then sum them.  But this is likely to be inferior to most other approaches, depending on the type of regression model, the other variables available, and why you are doing this.  Why not tell us a little more about those things?

Comment: regressors are variables measuring social and economically situation of the sample.. for example "social class" measured by categories from 1 to 5.. "job situation" measured by categories from 1 to 5.. ecc..

Comment: A different way to approach this is to leave *Trust* as a dichotomous variable and then use *GM*, *PM* and *PI* as independent variables along with your other independent variables.  (So each person has three observations:  *Trust* for *GM*, *Trust* for *PM*, and *Trust* for *PI*).This may or may not make sense for your situation.